# An ImageView that keep the size of 4cm on all devices?

Tags: java, android, size, screen

I have an Image view with pictures in it (they are all the exact same size) and the image view should keep it's size over all devices, htc, sony, samsung, and so on. it's not important which exact size, it should be between 3.8x3.8 cm and 4.5x4.5 cm. that means, if I'll take a scale and measure the size on screens of different devices, it should be always the same numbers.

xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
         >

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/testanzeige"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:src="@drawable/info" 
         android:layout_width="231dp"
            android:layout_height="231dp"/>
```

Comment: Use dp in the ImageView size, so it can keep the same size on screen with different densities. And to get the size do some testing with values and measure on your phone screen until you get the size you want.

Comment: Already have this one, but not with the wished result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at [More Resource Types](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension)

There is a unit called **mm** for Millimeters. (10mm are equal to 1cm)

```
mm Millimeters - Based on the physical size of the screen
```

in your case you just use  **40mm**x**40mm**.

```
<ImageView
       android:id="@+id/testanzeige"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:src="@drawable/info" 
       android:layout_width="40mm"
       android:layout_height="40mm"/>
```

Comment: Very nice thx to you.

but it tolded me, that if I do this, it won't work on some devices. what about that?

Comment: you're welcome!  yes, it's not recommanded to use **mm**. For example when you put a big number as width(or height), maybe the device width(or height) is less than this number so your app can crash.